# Issues in interpolation and extrapolation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data for 2014 and 2022.

I want to (linearly) interpolate and extrapolate values for year 2010 to 2023.

The code below interpolates but does not extrapolate (repeats the values of 2014 and 2022).

Can you please help me fix them.

```
# Load the tidyverse and zoo packages
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

# Your initial data
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(2014, 2022),
  cities = rep(c("City1", "City2", "City3", "City4", "City5"), each = 2),
  population = c(100, 200, 150, 250, 120, 220, 170, 270, 130, 230),
  mean_income = c(50000, 60000, 55000, 65000, 48000, 58000, 53000, 63000, 49000, 59000),
  col1 = c(10, 20, 15, 25, 12, 22, 17, 27, 13, 23),
  col2 = c(30, 40, 35, 45, 32, 42, 37, 47, 33, 43),
  col100 = c(1000, 1100, 1050, 1150, 1020, 1120, 1070, 1170, 1030, 1130)
)

# Generate a sequence of years from 2010 to 2023
all_years <- seq(2010, 2023, by = 1)

# Perform linear extrapolation for selected columns
result_df <- df %>%
  complete(cities, year = all_years) %>%
  group_by(cities) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("col"), ~ na.approx(., method = "linear", rule = 2), .names = "extrapolated_{.col}"))

# View the result
print(result_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `na.spline`

```
result_df <- df %>%
  complete(cities, year = all_years) %>%
  group_by(cities) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("col"), na.spline, .names = "extrapolated_{.col}"))
```